# BlowfishPasswordHasher doesnt allow login

Tags: php, cakephp

In cakephp  have changed from simplePasswordHasher to BlowfishPasswordHasher . I add the following code and comment out all refernces to the old simplehasher method but I cant login. I can create a new user with BlowfishPasswordHasher but logins now dont work?

The link below didnt fix the problem as I just cant login but I can see the new user with correct salted password

[CakePHP - How do I implement blowfish hashing for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113819/cakephp-how-do-i-implement-blowfish-hashing-for-passwords)

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

```
//userscontroller
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
           return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); //for 2.3 and above versions, docs are old

        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}  

//user
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
    }
    return true;
}

//new user
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <h2><?php echo __('Add User2'); ?></h2>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
```

//in appcontroller
public $components = array( "Email", 'Session', 'Auth');

public function beforeFilter() {

```
        $this->Auth->authError = 'You cant access this page';
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect= array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect= array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'login'  );
        $this->Auth->authorize= array('Controller');
        $this->Auth->unauthorizedRedirect=  '/users/dashboard'; 
        $this->set("logged_in", $this->Auth->loggedIn())

//user model
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        )
```

Comment: What's the length of your password field? Blowfish hashes are longer than sha1.

Comment: varchar(255) is this correct?

Comment: Yup that's long enough, though if you changed it recently be sure to clear model cache.

Comment: i didnt change the password field in mysql so what is the problem with it ?

Comment: You haven't included your Auth config in the post. Is it properly configured to use BlowfishPasswordHasher?

Comment: What does you Auth component configuration look like? (@ADmad beat me to it) And are you sure you are trying to login with a newly created user, ie one that actually has a blowfish hash in the database? And before any further wild guessing starts, what have you tried so far to debug the problem?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the auth config. anything more let me know and I  dont get any error apart from invalid user on a newly created user with blowfishpasswordhasher. How do i config properly to BlowfishPasswordHasher as this might be the issue which I didnt pick up in the docs

Comment: ok thanks , this in the beforefilter would be what? 'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't configured Auth to use `BlowfishPasswordHasher` so it's still uses the default hasher. Specify the `passwordHasher` key as shown in eg. [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout).